# Overarching Conjectures and Hierarchy of Mathematical Conjectures

Tags: number-theory, big-list, conjectures

I am interested in the Hierarchy and Connections between various different [open problems in Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsolved_problems_in_mathematics), and the most general conjectures in various fields of Mathematics.

**Examples of Hierachy**

*Solved*

- [Fermat's Last Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) $\subset$ [Tanijama-Shimura Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_theorem) $\subset$ [Serre's modularity conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%27s_modularity_conjecture)
- [Fermat's Last Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) $\subset$ [Euler's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture) (counterexamples known, therefore too strong)
- [Poincarè conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture) $\subset$ [Geometrization conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrization_conjecture)

*Unsolved*

- [Fermat's Last Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) with big exponents $\subseteq$ [ABC-conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture)
- [Twin Prime Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) $\subset$ [Hardy–Littlewood conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture#First_Hardy.E2.80.93Littlewood_conjecture) $\subset$ [Schinzel's hypothesis H](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H) $\subset$ [Bateman–Horn conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman%E2%80%93Horn_conjecture)
- [Riemann hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis) $\subset$ [Generalized Riemann hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Riemann_hypothesis) $\subset$ [Grand Riemann hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Riemann_hypothesis)
- [Cramér's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture) $\subset$ [Firoozbakht's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firoozbakht%27s_conjecture)
- [P vs. PSPACE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSPACE) $\subset$ [P vs. NP-Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_%3D_NP_problem) $\subseteq$ [Existance of One-Way-Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_functions)

**Examples of Overarching Conjectures**

- [Schanuel's Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture) in transcendence theory
- [Bateman–Horn conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman%E2%80%93Horn_conjecture) in prime number theory
- [Existance of One-Way-Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_functions) in complexity theory

**Questions**

1. Are there complete lists of the dependencies between different conjectures in mathematics available?
2. What are the most general Conjectures in various fields of Mathematics?
3. (How can one ask this questions in a better way?)

Comment: Schanuel's Conjecture implies a great many known theorems and open conjectures in transcendence theory. Schinzel's Hypothesis H implies a great many conjectures in prime number theory.

Comment: I think that ABC conjecture implies FLT only for big enough exponents, so it is not clear if it is a strictly stronger statement.

Comment: Thanks Ferra, I didn't think about this. I added this in the post. Are relations between ABC and FLT known that show that either the one is stronger than the other? For example, is it known that FLT could *not* imply ABC for big exponents?

Comment: I believe Schinzel's Hypothesis H doesn't necessarily imply the Hardy-Littlewood conjecture, but Bateman-Horn still implies both of them

Answer (score 4):

The Riemann Hypothesis is a special case of the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis, which is a special case of the [Grand Riemann Hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Riemann_hypothesis).

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. Didnt know about the Grand RH. If you have another two hierarchies, the bounty is yours ;)